# Mechanics of system of particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

[image]

It is easy to prove that velocity before and after collision remain same in cm frame of reference but here we have to prove velocity of cm remain same .

Answer (score 1):

Use conservation of momentum to find a connection between the velocities before and after the collision.
Use the velocities before the collision to find the velocity of the centre of mass.
Now use the velocities after collision to find the velocity the centre of mass.

Use the conservation of momentum relationship to compare the velocity of the centre of mass found using the two different sets of velocities.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $m_1u_1+m_2u_2 = m1v_1+m_2v_2$ because of conservation of momentum.

We can also scale time and shift axes so that the collision occurs at $x=0$ and $t=0$. In this case, the position of the particles before the collision is $u_1t$ and $u_2t$ and after is $v_1t$ and $v_2t$.

So the centre of mass position before is $m_1u_1t+m_2u_2t = t(m_1u_1+m_2u_2)$ and after is $m_1v_1t+m_2v_2t = t(m_1v_1+m_2v_2)$.